# SDL_Texture not found by compiler

Tags: c++, textures, sdl

So, I'm trying to make a wrapper for `SDL_RenderCopy()` and for some reason, I keep getting an error that says "use of undefined type 'SDL_Texture'". I have all SDL2's libraries linked and headers included. Here's the code:

```
void drawImage(Uint32 tex, float x, float y){
    SDL_Rect rec;
    rec.x = x;
    rec.y = y;
    if(vcTextures.size() > tex){ //If the argument is in range
        if(vcTextures[tex] != 0){ //If the index points to an image
            rec.w = vcTextures[tex]->w;
            rec.h = vcTextures[tex]->h;
            SDL_RenderCopy(gvRender, vcTextures[tex], 0, &rec);
        };
    };
};
```

`vcTextures` is of type `vector<SDL_Texture*>` to store the addresses of all loaded textures for easy cleanup at the end of execution. This is the only place where this happens. When I click on the message that says "see declaration of 'SDL_Texture'", it shows me the declaration, so I know the type exists as far as the file is concerned.

Here's the full error message:

```
1>f:\c++\xyg\xyg_runtime\graphics.cpp(125) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'SDL_Texture'
1>        d:\sdl2\vc\include\sdl_render.h(127) : see declaration of 'SDL_Texture'
1>f:\c++\xyg\xyg_runtime\graphics.cpp(125) : error C2227: left of '->w' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Comment: And you have the SDL header included in *this* source file? Can you please edit your question to include the *actual* compiler output, as text, copy-pasted (and not rewritten or edited) and complete (including any other warnings, errors or informational messages)? And if possible, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us as well.

Comment: Yes, I have it included in that source file, and I added the full error message. I'll have to write a whole new program to provide an MCVE, so that's gonna take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to access members of SDL_Texture directly. It is an [opaque type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type). I'm pretty sure the documentation doesn't make any mention of members `w` or `h`, so I don't know where you got the idea to do that. If you want to get information about the texture, you can use [`SDL_QueryTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_QueryTexture).

```
SDL_QueryTexture(vcTextures[tex], nullptr, nullptr, &rec.w, &rec.h);
```

Comment: That wasn't mentioned in the wiki page for SDL_Texture. Then again, a lot of SDL2's wiki is very incomplete. I'll see if this works.